# How to plot the whole point circle above axis line in matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib

Normally when you plot a list of points and axis. Only a part of point will be shown for those intersecting with the axis line, see the first point in this [png](http://matplotlib.org/pyplots/pyplot_two_subplots.png) for an example. How to make sure the whole point circle in shown above the axis line?

Comment: Adjust the axis limits so they're slightly larger than the extreme points.

Comment: The `clip_on=False` solution is better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can turn off clipping for the resulting plot artist(s) by setting `clip_on=False` in your call to plot or scatter.  Note that you can also modify the clipping box by hand if you have a reference to the artist.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot([0,1,2], [0,1,2], 'bo', clip_on=False)
```

produces:

[image: un-clipped scatter plot]

Comment: This is exactly what I want. Thank you for this nice example!

Answer (score 1):

You can turn off the clipping by using the parameter `clip_on` of the plotting functions:

```
plt.plot(range(10), marker='o', ms=20, clip_on=False)
```